# Aero Previews Stop Working Sporadically

Tags: windows-7, windows, taskbar, aero

This problem is a little difficult to diagnose, but many times I've noticed that on my Windows 7 machine the previews that pop up when hovering over items in my taskbar do not show up.

When hovering over a taskbar entry, normally the application's entry will light up with a color contained within the application's icon. Also, normally, when mousing out of the taskbar, the glow fades away. When the problem I described above happens, that glow is persistently over the last entry of the taskbar I hovered.

I have attached a screencast that clarifies my last paragraph. Hopefully someone can identify why this randomly happens. It reminds me a little bit of that old problem with Windows where tooltips of tray icons would show up behind the taskbar.

Screencast: http://www.screenr.com/cjSs

**Note:** Before anyone says this might have to do with the custom visual style I'm using, it doesn't; I just installed this style a few days ago, and before that all I had was the normal Aero interface. The problem still occurred.

Comment: Link doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me; try visiting http://www.screenr.com/user/skoshy and clicking on the video there.

Comment: I still can't get to it

Answer (score 0):

Odd.  I'm curious if it is just a registry oddity.

Create a new user account and login to it.  Does the new account have previews?